# Singleton with multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, singleton

I've been trying to find a singleton implementation where:

- I can have a class `Application` which is abstract
- And there can be multiple classes derived from `Application`, for example `SampleApplication` and `OtherSampleApplication`.
- But I only want one instance of `Application`, whatever the actual type is, so I've been trying to make it a singleton.

Here's my current Singleton implementation:

```cpp
template<class T>
class Singleton
{
public:
    static T& GetInstance()
    {
      static T instance;
      return instance;
    }

    Singleton(Singleton const&) = delete;
    Singleton(Singleton&&) = delete;
    Singleton& operator=(Singleton const&) = delete;
    Singleton& operator=(Singleton&&) = delete;

protected:
    Singleton() = default;
    virtual ~Singleton() = default;
};
```

Then, for the derived classes, I've tried a number of things:

1. `class Application : public Singleton<Application>` with `class SampleApplication : public Application`
   This will not work because we're trying to create an `Application` instance instead of a `SampleApplication`.
2. `class Application : public Singleton<Application>` with `class SampleApplication : public Application, public Singleton<SampleApplication>`
   This doesn't compile because the `GetInstance()` is ambiguous. I tried to work around this with `virtual` inheritance but couldn't get it to compile.
3. `class Application` with `class SampleApplication : public Application, public Singleton<SampleApplication>`
   Doesn't meet the "requirements" I listed above because we can have another singleton of another derived class.

Does anyone know a way to accomplish this?

Comment: One possible approach is to use multiple inheritance (2) and explicitly specify preferable method in `SampleApplication` class: `public: using Singleton<SampleApplication>::GetInstance;`

Comment: Application abstract has the GetInstance, or alternatively `Singleton<Application>`, and `main` passes into the that the derived Application instance.  If the singleton has already been initialized with an instance, it disallows the second re-initialization (throw an exception? return error code? silently ignore?).

Comment: How are you planning to use this if you make it work? I'm not getting a clear picture of where you are planning to let the dynamic dispatch to come in, since you are storing a plain `T` in your singleton.

Comment: There can be only one `Application` object, and that object is a sub-object of a class derived from `Application`. Therefore, there can be only one class derived from `Application` that gets instantiated when the program runs, right? Do you know at compile time which derived class this is?

Comment: @dewaffled Doing so and adding another `OtherSampleApplication` class, you can have things like:
`SampleApplication& application = SampleApplication::GetInstance();`
`OtherSampleApplication& otherApplication = OtherSampleApplication::GetInstance();`

Comment: @JaMiT I believe there's no solution for this if we don't know the derived type at compile-time. So, what's your idea?

Comment: @super Either by somehow overriding the `GetInstance` function with the `using` statement "dewaffled" was suggesting OR I probably have to change that into a pointer.

Comment: @Eljay I don't think I understood that, can you expand on that?

Comment: @DanielMarques and what would you want in this case? compilation error? i don't think there is a way to allow only one inheriting class because they e.g. may be in different translation units and not even "visible" to the compiler both at the same time.

Comment: @dewaffled Yes, compilation error would be ideal, but I would settle for a runtime error. You're right, it's likely not possible then

Comment: `void SetInstance(std::unique_ptr<Application> app) { if (instance) throw std::logic_error("singleton application already initialized"); instance = std::move(app); }`

Comment: If you do know the type at compile-time.. then what's the point? Just use a `Singleton<WhateverYouKnowYouWantAtCompileTime>` and leave it at that.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned that you will settle for a runtime error:

```
template<class T>
class Singleton : private ReallySingleton {
```

The rest of the singleton is as is. The private base class will go something like this:

```
class ReallySingleton {

   static int counter=0;

protected:
   ReallySingleton()
   {
      if (++counter > 1)
        throw std::runtime_error{"Too many singletons"};
   }
};
```

(`ReallySingleton::counter` will need to be defined somewhere where that's convenient)

Answer (score 1):

This solution shows how only allowing one instance based on a baseclass can work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// type for checking if something is a singleton later
struct SingletonBase 
{
};

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// specialized singleton to be used in baseclass (Application)
// keeps track of whether an instance of the baseclass has already been made
template<typename T>
struct Singleton : 
    public SingletonBase
{
    Singleton() 
    {
        has_instance = true;
    }

    static bool has_instance;
};

// has_instance initilization
template<typename T>
bool Singleton<T>::has_instance = false;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Baseclass for applications.

class Application :
    public Singleton<Application>
{
protected:
    Application() = default; // do not allow client code to make instance of base class
};

class SomeOtherKindOfApplication :
    public Singleton<SomeOtherKindOfApplication>
{
protected:
    SomeOtherKindOfApplication() = default;
};

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// application types derived from Application and SomeOtherApplication 

class Application1 :
    public Application
{
public:
    void Hello() 
    {
        std::cout << "Hello, " << std::endl;
    }
};

class Application2 :
    public Application
{
public:
    void World()
    {
        std::cout << "World !" << std::endl;
    }
};

class SomeOtherKindOfApplication1 :
    public SomeOtherKindOfApplication
{
public:
    void Bye()
    {
        std::cout << "Bye!" << std::endl;
    }
};

class NotASingleton
{
};

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Singleton instance getter

template<typename T>
static T& GetInstance()
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<SingletonBase, T>, "Can only create instances of classes derived from singleton");
    if (T::has_instance)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("An application instance has already been made");
    }

    static T instance;
    return instance;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
    auto instance = GetInstance<Application1>();
    instance.Hello();

    try
    {
        // getting an instance of another application derived
        // from Application will fail (runtime)
        auto instance2 = GetInstance<Application2>();
        instance2.World();
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    // but getting application with another baseclass should be fine
    auto instance3 = GetInstance<SomeOtherKindOfApplication1>();
    instance3.Bye();

    // next line will not even compile, NotASingleton isn't a singleton
    // auto no_instance = GetInstance<NotASingleton>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an approach that will produce compile-time errors if there is more than one class derived from `Application`. Usually. It is not fool-proof, and it does have drawbacks. I think it is worth considering.
*Given the class name "Application", I guess that this is potentially part of a library. If the library is not header-only, there is an extra consideration that I'll address that at the end.*

The overall picture for this approach is simple inheritance, plus an extra step for whomever defines a class derived from `Application`.

```cpp
class Application       : public Singleton<Application> { /* ... */ };
class SampleApplication : public Application            { /* ... */ };
REGISTER_APPLICATION(SampleApplication)     // Must not be in a header
```

The last line will be explained later.

First, let's hide `Singleton<Application>::GetInstance()`, which will not compile since `Application` is abstract. (I am assuming that everyone will type the shorter `Application::GetInstance()` to use this function; if not, this approach is scrap.) Add the function declaration to the abstract class, but *do not add a definition yet.*

```cpp
class Application : public Singleton<Application> {
  public:
    static Application & GetInstance();

    // ...
};
```

The definition will be added elsewhere, *not in a header file.* Taking the definition out of header files is the reason for hiding the function in the `Singleton` template. (While the `extern` keyword allows moving some template definitions out of header files, my understanding is that it does not fully suppress an inline definition when there is one, as in this case.) Where will the definition of `GetInstance()` live? That's where the extra step comes in. It's also where I could get blasted because Macros Are Evil unless they are needed. It's needed. Put the definition of this function in a macro.

```cpp
#define REGISTER_APPLICATION(name)       \
Application& Application::GetInstance()  \
{                                        \
    static name instance;                \
    return instance;                     \
}
```

Now document that when deriving from `Application`, this macro must be used in a source file, not a header file. The parameter to the macro is the name of the derived class; if the derived class is `SampleApplication` then the line to add to the source file is `REGISTER_APPLICATION(SampleApplication)`.

---

### So what happens when someone messes up?

**If the macro is not used,** the linker will complain about the undefined reference to `Application::GetInstance()`. Unfortunately, this is not as clear about the problem as I would like. Probably put an entry in your framework's FAQ covering this.

**If the macro is used twice,** the linker will complain about multiple definitions of `Application::GetInstance()`. This is why the definition cannot be given inline. We want the one definition rule to apply. This is not fool-proof (maybe there are two classes derived from `Application` and only one remembered the macro), but it might be adequate.

---

For a library where parts of `Application` are defined outside headers, there would be a problem in that `Application::GetInstance()` cannot be part of the library, leading to an undefined reference when compiling the library. One solution for that is to make `Application` a wrapper for another class that is supposed to be internal to the library. For example:

```cpp
class Application : public InternalApplication, public Singleton<Application> {
    static Application & GetInstance();
    // Everything else is inherited from InternalApplication.
};
```

Now `Application` can be header-only, while `InternalApplication` can have components in a static (or dynamic) library.